# Create views for different versions of the iphone

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm creating a project that will run on versions, since the iphone 4 until iPhone 6 We all know that the resolution of the screens are different for each device.

In my case, to get around this I created three files .xib type, and in each one I modified the size of the view in xcode inspector attributes tab to stick with the same size of the devices.

I wonder if this way I'm doing is correct, and if there is no other better?

Answer (score 0):

Of course. You should use AutoLayout.
Check the [manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html).

How it works at a glance: you just setting different relations between views in Interface Builder. It looks like:

[image]